# Allow formatting for specific cells on a protected sheet

Tags: excel

I have an Excel worksheet where I want formatting for the majority of cells to remain locked, while allowing a few specific cells to be edited and formatted by the user.

However, when protecting a worksheet, it seems the permission "Format cells" applies to all cells on the sheet, including those that are unlocked.

Does anybody know of a workaround to allow formatting of specific, individual cells that remain unlocked, while preventing formatting of locked cells?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way (VBA):

```
ActiveSheet.Protect Contents:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=False
```